# Telerik Nested view

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

Below is my code for nested grid of telerik:

I have a problem to "find" controls(PreviousDate and DateofBirth) using  javascript.

```
<%@ Page Language="c#" CodeFile="DefaultCS.aspx.cs" Inherits="Telerik.GridExamplesCSharp.Hierarchy.NestedViewTemplate.DefaultCS" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>


<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Charting" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>   



    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


function showPreviousDate(sender, eventArgs) {

var Grid = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>");

 var MasterTable = Grid.get_masterTableView.get_dataItems();

 for (var i = 0; i < MasterTable.get_dataItems().length; i++) {

var row = MasterTable.get_dataItems()[i];

}

}

 </script>

<body>

 <form id="form1" runat="server"> 

   <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="tabPrevious" runat="server"   
   ActiveTabIndex="0"/>

   <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Previous records" 

   ID="tabPrevious"/>

   <ContentTemplate>

    <telerik:RadGrid RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="RadGrid1" 

     OnPreRender="RadGrid1_PreRender" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"

    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" 

    AllowMultiRowSelection="False"

    AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" GridLines="None" ShowGroupPanel="true"

    OnItemCreated="RadGrid1_ItemCreated"

    OnItemCommand="RadGrid1_ItemCommand">

    <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages"></PagerStyle>

    <MasterTableView DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GroupLoadMode="Server">

      <NestedViewTemplate>

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="viewWrap" 

        Visible="false">                                   

          <table runat="server" style="width: 100%;">

            <tr>

               <td align="center">Previous Records </td>

            </tr>



            <tr>

              <td align="center">

        <table>

             <tr>

               <td style="padding-right: 20px">

                <asp:Label ID="labelDOb" runat="server" Text="Date of Birth" Width="100px"></asp:Label>

               <telerik:RadDatePicker SharedCalendarID="SharedCalendar"         
     ShowPopupOnFocus="true" Enabled="false" RenderMode="Lightweight"  
      ID="DateofBirth" runat="server">                                                          

               </telerik:RadDatePicker>

              </td>


               <td style="padding-right: 20px">


                   <asp:Label ID="labelDate" runat="server" Text="Previous Date" Width="100px">

                 </asp:Label>

                  <telerik:RadDatePicker SharedCalendarID="SharedCalendar" ShowPopupOnFocus="true" 

              Enabled="false" RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="PreviousDate" runat="server">

          <ClientEvents OnDateSelected="showPreviousDate" />

                  </telerik:RadDatePicker>

              </td>

            </tr>   

        </table>

      </td>

     </tr>

  </table>

</asp:Panel>

</NestedViewTemplate>  

</MasterTableView>

</telerik:RadGrid>

</ContentTemplate>

</ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>

</ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript with Telerik controls is never pretty, but you should be able to use classes and navigate to the other control in the same row with something like this.  Note this is NOT TESTED

```
function showPreviousDate(sender, eventArgs) {

var thisID = sender.get_id();
var dateOfBirthControl, previousDateControl

if (thisID.indexOf("Birth") > -1){
    //sender is the date of birth picker, and we have to find the other one
    dateOfBirthControl = sender;
    previousDateControl = $find($("#" + sender.get_id).parent().next().find(".PrevDateControl").prop("id"));
}
else {
    //sender is the previousDateControl picker, and we have to find the other
    previousDateControl = sender;
    dateOfBirthControl = $find($("#" + sender.get_id).parent().prev().find(".BirthDateControl").prop("id"));
}

}
```

Make sure to add the CssClasses to your DatePickers if you are going to try this

Comment: Hi, Thanks for sharing. I came across an error
Object doesn't support property or method 'prop'.

Comment: I guess I don't use jQuery enough to be good at it.  Try the updated version.  Anyway, this is more to give you an idea of how to go about it.

Comment: Glad I could help!  If you think this is the answer, then please mark it as such.  Good luck!